# R: Iterating over a data.table, with replacements

Tags: r, loops, replace, data.table

I've been racking my head over this over the past few days. I have a dataset that appears as follows:

```
V1 <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "B", "A", "A", "D")
V2 <- c("B", "E", "A", "G", "C", "G", "E", "B")

R1 <- c(120, 195, 135, 30, 195, 120, 120, 30)
G1 <- c(0, 195, 0, 195, 195, 0, 0, 195)
B1 <- c(240, 195, 0, 135, 195, 240, 240, 135)

R2 <- c(195, 60, 120, 75, 135, 75, 60, 195)
G2 <- c(195, 15, 0, 15, 0, 15, 15, 195)
B2 <- c(195, 150, 240, 150, 0, 150, 150, 195)

cross <- data.frame(V1,V2,R1,G1,B1,R2,G2,B2)
```

This is a grossly simplified version of my actual dataset, which is a lot larger with over 60,000 observations. In the first two columns, `V1` and `V2` denote ID variables. Then `R1`, `B1` and `G1` correspond to the attributes associated with `V1` and, likewise, `R2`, `B2` and `G2` are the attributes of `V2` (this is a network model, mapping which nodes are linked to which nodes and the associated attributes of those nodes, but that's beside the point here). This gives a data.frame that looks like:

```
  V1 V2  R1  G1  B1  R2  G2  B2
1  A  B 120   0 240 195 195 195
2  B  E 195 195 195  60  15 150
3  C  A 135   0   0 120   0 240
4  D  G  30 195 135  75  15 150
5  B  C 195 195 195 135   0   0
6  A  G 120   0 240  75  15 150
7  A  E 120   0 240  60  15 150
8  D  B  30 195 135 195 195 195
```

Note that IDs that appear in `V1` can also appear in `V2`. Also note that the associated attributes for each ID is unique and uniform across the dataset.

Now, what I want to do is iterate through each row and calculate a series of means. After the first iteration of this process, my data should look like:

```
  V1 V2    R1     G1      B1     R2    G2      B2
1  A  B 157.5   97.5   217.5  157.5  97.5   217.5
2  B  E   195    195     195     60    15     150
3  C  A   135      0       0    120     0     240
4  D  G    30    195     135     75    15     150
5  B  C   195    195     195    135     0       0
6  A  G   120      0     240     75    15     150
7  A  E   120      0     240     60    15     150
8  D  B    30    195     135    195   195     195
```

i.e., `R1` and `R2` is the mean of its prior two respective values for the first row, `120` and `195`. And so on.

*Then*, that mean is reinserted as the new attributes (matched to ID), and the process starts again with the next row. After this step, my dataset should look like:

```
  V1 V2    R1     G1      B1     R2    G2      B2
1  A  B 157.5   97.5   217.5  157.5  97.5   217.5
2  B  E 157.5   97.5   217.5     60    15     150
3  C  A   135      0       0  157.5  97.5   217.5
4  D  G    30    195     135     75    15     150
5  B  C 157.5   97.5   217.5    135     0       0
6  A  G 157.5   97.5   217.5     75    15     150
7  A  E 157.5   97.5   217.5     60    15     150
8  D  B    30    195     135  157.5  97.5   217.5
```

Thus, all attributes for `A` and `B` have changed. The process would then continue for the second row (for `B` and `E`) and so on. The process continues until the last row is reached.

Here is my code so far. I have not used `data.table` as that's what I'm trying to figure out. But here it is. It works, but it's *extremely slow*, making it difficult for me to explore what's going on in the system.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(cross)){
  Rc <- (cross[i,3] + cross[i,6]) / 2 
  Gc <- (cross[i,4] + cross[i,7]) / 2 
  Bc <- (cross[i,5] + cross[i,8]) / 2 
  V1c <- cross[i,"V1"]
  V2c <- cross[i,"V2"]
  
  cross$R1 <- with(cross, replace(R1, V1 == V1c, Rc)) 
  cross$G1 <- with(cross, replace(G1, V1 == V1c, Gc))  
  cross$B1 <- with(cross, replace(B1, V1 == V1c, Bc)) 
  
  cross$R1 <- with(cross, replace(R1, V1 == V2c, Rc)) 
  cross$G1 <- with(cross, replace(G1, V1 == V2c, Gc))  
  cross$B1 <- with(cross, replace(B1, V1 == V2c, Bc)) 
  
  cross$R2 <- with(cross, replace(R2, V2 == V2c, Rc)) 
  cross$G2 <- with(cross, replace(G2, V2 == V2c, Gc))  
  cross$B2 <- with(cross, replace(B2, V2 == V2c, Bc)) 
  
  cross$R2 <- with(cross, replace(R2, V2 == V1c, Rc)) 
  cross$G2 <- with(cross, replace(G2, V2 == V1c, Gc))  
  cross$B2 <- with(cross, replace(B2, V2 == V1c, Bc)) 
}
```

This process takes longer than one hour given the size of my data. From what I gather, `data.table` is supposed to be much faster. I've tried almost everything, ranging from tidyverse stuff to converting into matrices. I've even subsetted the data that needs to be replaced. But I'm having quite a lot of difficulty trying to figure out using `data.table` for this, which apparently would skip the need to use a `for` loop.

If it's any help, the slow part of the loop seems to be the section where variables get replaced, not when they are generated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are attributes associated with `V` different across the rows (quote: 'Then R1, B1 and G1 correspond to the attributes associated with V1')? For example, in row 1 A has values: 120, 0, 240, while in row 3: 120, 0, 120.

Comment: You're right. Sloppy stuff on my part. I've now corrected all that. The dataset should make sense now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a big fan of `data.table`, but I don't think it's needed here. Instead of updating all matching entries in the whole `data.frame` on each iteration, just update a reference matrix by index.

```
V1 <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "B", "A", "A", "D")
V2 <- c("B", "E", "A", "G", "C", "G", "E", "B")

R1 <- c(120, 195, 135, 30, 195, 120, 120, 30)
G1 <- c(0, 195, 0, 195, 195, 0, 0, 195)
B1 <- c(240, 195, 0, 135, 195, 240, 240, 135)

R2 <- c(195, 60, 120, 75, 135, 75, 60, 195)
G2 <- c(195, 15, 0, 15, 0, 15, 15, 195)
B2 <- c(195, 150, 240, 150, 0, 150, 150, 195)

V12 <- c(V1, V2)
uids <- unique(V12)
idx1 <- match(V1, uids)
idx2 <- match(V2, uids)
mRef <- matrix(c(R1, R2, G1, G2, B1, B2), ncol = 3)[match(uids, V12),]
```

`mRef` is a matrix of `R`, `G`, `B` values for the unique IDs in `V1` and `V2`. The `idx` vectors point to the rows of `mRef` corresponding to the IDs in `V1` and `V2`.

Here's a quick little `Rcpp` function to iterate through `idx1` and `idx2` to update mRef.

```
Rcpp::cppFunction('NumericMatrix updatecross(const IntegerVector& id1, const IntegerVector& id2, NumericMatrix attr) {
  const int idrows = id1.length();
  const int attrcols = attr.ncol();
  double newval = 0;

  for (int col = 0; col < attrcols; col++) {
    for (int row = 0; row < idrows; row++) {
      newval = (attr(id1(row), col) + attr(id2(row), col))/2;
      attr(id1(row), col) = newval;
      attr(id2(row), col) = newval;
    }
  }

  return attr;
}')
```

Update `mRef` and build the final `data.frame` using the `idx` vectors.

```
mRef <- updatecross(idx1 - 1L, idx2 - 1L, mRef)
cross <- cbind(data.frame(V1, V2),
               setNames(cbind(as.data.frame(mRef[idx1,]),
                              as.data.frame(mRef[idx2,])),
                        c("R1", "G1", "B1", "R2", "G2", "B2")))

cross
#>   V1 V2       R1      G1       B1       R2      G2       B2
#> 1  A  B 104.0625 66.5625 154.6875  90.0000 78.7500 144.3750
#> 2  B  E  90.0000 78.7500 144.3750 104.0625 66.5625 154.6875
#> 3  C  A 127.5000 52.5000 146.2500 104.0625 66.5625 154.6875
#> 4  D  G  90.0000 78.7500 144.3750  99.3750 76.8750 125.6250
#> 5  B  C  90.0000 78.7500 144.3750 127.5000 52.5000 146.2500
#> 6  A  G 104.0625 66.5625 154.6875  99.3750 76.8750 125.6250
#> 7  A  E 104.0625 66.5625 154.6875 104.0625 66.5625 154.6875
#> 8  D  B  90.0000 78.7500 144.3750  90.0000 78.7500 144.3750
```

D and B are everywhere the same because they were the last to be updated. Similarly, A and E are everywhere the same because neither was updated after row 7.

Comment: You're a wizard! That worked very quickly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Using `igraph` (not sure if this will be any faster):

```
library(igraph)
library(purrr)

vertices <- tibble(
  V = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "G", "E"),
  R = c(120, 195, 135, 30, 75, 60),
  G = c(0, 195, 0, 195, 15, 15),
  B = c(240, 195, 0, 195, 150, 150)
)

edges <- tibble(
  from = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "B",  "A", "A", "D"),
  to = c("B", "E", "A", "G", "C", "G", "E", "B")
)

g <- graph_from_data_frame(edges, vertices = vertices, directed = FALSE)

for(iRow in seq_len(nrow(edges))){
  
  v <- as.character(edges[iRow,])
  
  values <- igraph::vertex.attributes(g, v) %>%
    .[-1] %>%
    map_dbl(mean) 
  
  for(iAttr in names(values))
    vertex_attr(g, iAttr, v) <- values[[iAttr]]
}

as_tibble(vertex.attributes(g))
```

result:

```
  name      R     G     B
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A     104.   66.6  162.
2 B      90    78.8  159.
3 C     128.   52.5  146.
4 D      90    78.8  159.
5 G      99.4  76.9  141.
6 E     104.   66.6  162.
```

I'm not sure what this process represents, final result is dependent of the sequence of merging described by your data. Can you maybe share your original problem from which this one is derived?

Comment: This works, and indeed I was using igraph before transitioning from igraph objects to dataframes. But in terms of speed, the Rcpp solution above seems to cut it. Thanks for your help anyway!